# Drupal 7 xautoload composer

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, drupal-7, composer-php

So I have the Paypal REST API installed ( https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php ) with Composer in my_drupal_module/lib/Drupal/ and now I want to use the namespaces in a function in my module. I understood that I need something like xautoload ( https://drupal.org/project/xautoload ) to do that so I tried something like:

$payer = new \Drupal\vendor\PayPal\Api\Payer;

with and without the first slash, and with and without parentheses at the end but it didn't work. I added:

require **DIR** . '/lib/Drupal/vendor/autoload.php';

but still nothing so I commented it. Meanwhile I found this: https://drupal.org/node/1976206 that explains this issue but it is unclear to me what exactly to write in hook_xautoload() or direct registration for the setup that I have. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I solved it. Thanks to proloy03 who gave me the idea: https://drupal.org/node/2096621

You don't need xautoload to load the classes and namespace just implement hook_init to require it like so:

```
function my_module_init() {
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

and then in your function write:

```
$payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
```

and it all works.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. For taking the time to post this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use hook_init(). This is a global hook that fires on ever single page load to your Drupal site. It's extremely expensive. Your Paypal library will load on every portion of the site, even when you don't need it.

Comment: Then what do you suggest? If you have found an alternative to my approach then please share it?

Answer (score 1):

With xautload you can do something like this...

In mymodule.module

```
function mymodule_libraries_info() {

'paypal' => array(
      'name' => 'PayPal SDK',
      'xautoload' => function($adapter) {
       $adapter->composerJson('composer.json'); 
     }
}
```

Declaring this allow you to use the namespace. Like

```
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
```

Check [xautoload.api.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/xautoload/tree/xautoload.api.php?h=7.x-5.x)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that you need XAutoload to use the Paypal API installed by Composer is wrong.

The only thing you need to make any code installed by Composer available is to include the Composer autoloader in your code execution path when you need any of the provided classes. The easiest form of this is to simply require the Composer autoloader in the very first index.php (or whatever Drupal uses) file that answers every request (possibly instantiating more Drupal classes, modules and stuff).

Once the code execution comes to your own code, the autoloading allows your code to include all the classes you included with Composer.

How to use the code? Don't invent your own namespace for the existing code, it will not work. "\Drupal\vendor\PayPal\Api\Payer" sounds pretty wrong to me, I suspect the correct namespace is "\PayPal\Api\Payer". And yes, [that file does indeed exist](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payer.php). So you have to use that.

If it still does not work, complaining the class could not be loaded, then the Composer autoloader file is not included in your scripts code path.

Comment: I'm using Paypal in a Drupal module, that needs to be standalone, modifing Drupal files like index.php is not an option, and is not recomended by anyone. I tried to require the autoloader and use the namespaces but the problem is that Drupal 7 was written before PHP 5.3, meaning before namespaces, and Drupal has kind of an issue with them. That's why I am asking this question.